# How to set the lifespan on a growl

Tags: primeng

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/growl

Im trying to get a growl to show for 3 seconds, what am I doing wrong? The growl displays, but doesnt fade away.

```
<form [formGroup]="editPostForm" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Title:</label>
        <input formControlName = "title" type="text" class="form-control" id="title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="post-body">Body:</label>            
        <p-editor formControlName="editor" [style]="{'height':'320px'}" id="text"></p-editor>            
    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="savePost()" class="btn btn-primary" >Save</button>
    <p-growl [(value)]="msgs" [life]=3000></p-growl>
</form>
```

**[update]**
correct syntax for setting the life property:

```
<p-growl [(value)]="msgs" life=3000 formControlName="gr1"></p-growl>
```

Comment: You could use this wrapper module https://www.npmjs.com/package/primeng-advanced-growl. This module offers you more advanced feature and abstracts your problem described above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the syntax, but based on the other attributes, have you tried these?

#### quotes

`[life]="3000"`

---

#### parentheses

`[(life)]=3000`

---

#### quotes and parentheses

`[(life)]="3000"`

Comment: the property is specified as a number

Comment: ok, I got it, its neither of these.  Its simply this<br/><p-growl [(value)]="msgs" life=3000 formControlName="gr1"></p-growl>